# How can LinearLayout transfer onPressed event to its child elements?

Tags: android, events, selector

I have a LinearLayout and its child - ImageView. My activity's onCreate does nothing but for setting content view. Content view's xml source looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"    
        android:background="@android:color/white"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where @drawable/selector is:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/foo1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/foo2"/>

</selector>
```

Case 1: I press ImageView.

Case 2: I press LinearLayout outside of ImageView.

In the 1st case ImageView changes its src image (from foo2 to foo1), in the 2nd case it doesn't change anything. How can I make ImageView change its src image in the 2nd case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

on your children xml elements.

Comment: Now it works in case 2, but doesn't work in case 1: ImageView receives onPressed event, but linear layout doesn't. How can I handle this if I want image view to change image in the 1st case as well?

Comment: Try setting 'clickable' to false on the ImageView, let the LinearLayout handle all the click events, and keep the 'duplicateParentState' on the ImageView to keep the two in sync.

Comment: i added android:clickable="false" & android:duplicateParentState="true" in child control. working fine now. thanx :)